Can Gradle ignore "Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format of string resource" in dependencies?
I am getting a ton of warnings when building my Android project, like:

/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/c6572b99c9121552ea/transformed/some-lib-5.9.2/res/values-zh-rCN/values-zh-rCN.xml:7420:4: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format of string resource string/hms_content_0x160900C0. Did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

I do understand why this message appears and I do know how to fix the resource. The problem is that this resource comes from a dependency that I cannot change.
Is there a way to tell Gradle to ignore this (or even all) warning(s) when coming from a dependency?
